# How can I display data from a search in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to show a list of titles from my search, but when I type any of the titles, listTile is not displayed as well as the `ProgressIndicator`. The `Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen: false)`.usernotes is a list of titles. How can I fix this?

```
class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var searchprovider =
        Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen: false).usernotes;

    var itemlist = [];
    var filteritems = [];
    bool isSearching = false;

    void descriptionlist({required String items}) async {
      setState(() {
        isSearching = true;
        searchprovider.forEach((element) {
          itemlist.add(element.description);
        });
        filteritems = itemlist
            .where((element) => element.contains(items.toLowerCase()))
            .toList();


        print(filteritems);
      });
      isSearching = false;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 50,
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (value) {
                descriptionlist(items: value);
              },
            )),
      ),
      body: isSearching
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : ListView.builder(
              itemCount: filteritems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                  filteritems[index],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                ));
              }),
    );
  }
}
```

The print values of `filteritems` shows that the titles I wanted to display exist.

Comment: Please tried out your idea but same result

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setState` after filtering the items so that the widget rebuilds with the updated `filteritems`. Additionally, you should wrap the CircularProgressIndicator widget inside a Visibility widget and set its visible property to `isSearching`. This way, the CircularProgressIndicator will only be visible while the search is in progress.

```dart
class _SearchState extends State<Search> {
  var searchprovider =
    Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen: false).usernotes;

  void descriptionlist({required String items}) async {
    setState(() {
      isSearching = true;
      itemlist.clear();

      searchprovider.forEach((element) {
        itemlist.add(element.description);
      });

      filteritems = itemlist
          .where((element) => element.contains(items.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();

      print(filteritems);
      isSearching = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var searchprovider =
        Provider.of<NotesProvider>(context, listen: false).usernotes;

    var itemlist = [];
    var filteritems = [];
    bool isSearching = false;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          width: 150,
          height: 50,
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (value) {
              descriptionlist(items: value);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: isSearching,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: filteritems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    filteritems[index],
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And please the ProgressIndicator clearly is also not showing